# python find root/parent based on list of tuples

Tags: python, list, relationship

Suppose i have list of tuples in which i store some keys (strings):

```
l=[
    (a,b),
    (b,c),
    (c,d),
    (d,e),
    (e,f),
    (w,x),
    (w,t),
    (t,q),
    (q,r),
    (q,u),

]
```

How can I find all the relations (especially HEAD) between tuples in list, eg:

```
a<-b<-c<-d<-e<-f
w<(-x,t-<q-<(r,u))
```

so i know that `f` is a grand grand grand grand child of `a`?

regards
JS.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of the following: `w<(-x,t-<q-<(r,u))`

Comment: Can these relationships be cyclical?  i.e, can `a<-b<-c<-a`

Comment: no, no cyclical. w is parent of x and t. t is parent of q. q is parent of r and u.

Answer (score 0):

We'll have a dictionary mapping names to`Node`s, and then build those nodes into trees.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        children = []
    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
    def ancestor_of(self, descendant):
        if self == descendant:
            return [self]
        for child in children:
            c=child.ancestor_of(descendant)
            if c:
                return [self, *c]
        return None

node_dict = defaultdict(Node)
for fst, snd in l: #assuming a and b are strings
    d[fst].add_child(d[snd])
#Query trees using ancestor_of
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

[image]

---

The source code is as follows.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

G = nx.DiGraph()

l=[
    ('a','b'),
    ('b','c'),
    ('c','d'),
    ('d','e'),
    ('e','f'),
    ('w','x'),
    ('w','t'),
    ('t','q'),
    ('q','r'),
    ('q','u')
    ]

for t in l:
    G.add_edge(t[0], t[1])

pos=graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)   
plt.show()
```